# Call Buttons with for loop

Tags: android, loops, button, for-loop

I'm designing a LevelSelect for my Game at the moment and want to lock them until the level before is done i.e: Level 1 is done: Level 2 is available rest is locked.
I created a int Variable which is the LevelNumber which was solved.
My question is how can i Unlock/Lock the buttons of the Levels which aren't unlocked yet?
I thought something like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= LvlDone+1; i++){
        (Lvl + i + Btn).visible=true;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to your views at that point? you should do btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); if you do have a reference, if not you need to use getIdentifier() to get a reference to the button and then set it's visibility.

Comment: But how i'm able to specify which button is visible?  
In example: LvlDone = 4 I want to make Button 1-5 Visible

Comment: ... Do you have a reference to your buttons, like a list of buttons? If not, you need to use getIdentifier() to get the id of the button, and then findViewById() to get a reference to the button from it's id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example :

```
ArrayList<Button> buttons;
int lvlDone;
// initialize variables 
...
for (int i = 0 ; i < buttons.size() ; i++) {
         buttons.get(i).setEnabled(i < lvlDone+2);
}
```

Comment: Better for (Button btn:buttons) { btn.setEnabled(i<lvlDone+2); }

Comment: This code won't work, you don't know what i is in btn.setEnabled(i < lvlDone+2); Your previous code (pre-edit) works though. This also requires you loop through all of your buttons, setting disabled buttons to disabled again once you have passed your last level to enable (your pre-edited one doesn't). Lastly, <= lvlDone+1 makes a little mores sense in reading too, but < lvlDone+2 obviously still works. Still a good answer, just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't written any Android stuff in forever, but could you create an object to hold the level buttons, and then do:

```
ArrayList<Button> levelButtons;

// TODO: Push buttons into levelButtons.

for (int i = 0; i <= LvlDone+1; i++) {
  levelButtons.get(i).visible = true;
}
```